# How to correct the time on Fullcalendar using Ajax And Flask?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

When i make an appointment on the calendar, the start and end time are showing correctly , but after i reload the page, i got a different datetime on the calendar and inside the database .

So for example, if i made an appointment from 09:00 AM to 10:30 AM, inside database i got this :

**Start**: 2017-04-30 15:00:00

**End**: 2017-04-30 16:30:00

My **view.py**:

```
appointment = Appointment()
appointment.start_time = parse_appoitment(start)
appointment.end_time = parse_appoitment(end)
appointment.note = data
appointment.user_id = abonent.id
appointment.client_id = client.id
db.session.add(appointment)
db.session.commit()
```

and also the date **parser**:

```
def parse_appoitment(time):
    start_datime = str(time)[0:25]
    date = parse(start_datime)
    return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Here is the `javascript` code:

```
{% if client.is_subscriber(master.id) %}
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var initialLocaleCode = 'ru';
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate();

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
      },
      defaultDate: moment(),
      // month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay listYear listMonth listWeek listDay
      defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      height: 650,
      locale: initialLocaleCode,
      local: 'GMT+06:00',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      select: function(start, end) {
          if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
              return false;
          } else {
            $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
          }
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
        var eventData;
        if (title) {
          eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
          };
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
          // console.log(eventData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{url_for("client.get_appo", abonent=master.slug)}}',
                    // contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data: {
              'title': title,
              'start': eventData['start']['_d'],
              'end': eventData['end']['_d']
            }
                })
                .done(function(data){

                    if(data.error){
                        // console.log(data.data);
                        console.log(eventData['start']['_d']);
                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log(data.data);
                        console.log(eventData['start']['_d']);
                    }

                });
        }
      },


      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {% for appo in master.appointments %}
          {% if appo.is_not_accepted %}
          {% endif %}
          {
            "title": "{{appo.note}}",
            "start": "{{appo.start_time}}",
            "end": "{{appo.end_time}}"
          },
        {% endfor %}
      ]
    });

    // build the locale selector's options
    $.each($.fullCalendar.locales, function(localeCode) {
      $('#locale-selector').append(
        $('<option/>')
          .attr('value', localeCode)
          .prop('selected', localeCode == initialLocaleCode)
          .text(localeCode)
      );
    });

    // when the selected option changes, dynamically change the calendar option
    $('#locale-selector').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'locale', this.value);
        $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
      }
    });
  });
{% endif %}
```

Am not sure by this `local: 'GMT+06:00',` , weither added it or not the same thing i got every time.

**Edit:**

I forgot to type the format that i got after submitting an appointment and before i parse it:

`Sun Apr 23 2017 15:30:00 GMT+0600 (+06)` to `Sun Apr 23 2017 17:00:00 GMT+0600 (+06)`

Here i made one from 09:30 to 11:00, but i got the above result .

Answer (score 0):

You must set timezone to local inside your settings as following:

`timezone: 'local'`

Now it works :) .